# Share Image in Twitter in Android using Intent

Tags: android, twitter, bitmap, share

Hello I try to use the share dialog using Intent with the code below. I want to share an image and text at the same time. However I get the `eror: Failed to insert image                                                           java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory`

My code is as below, am I doing anything wrong. The code is in a fragment class.

```
Bitmap image = bmResized;

String pathOfBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), image, "twitter_image.jpg", null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathOfBmp);

Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "here is the tweet text");

tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Share this via"));
```

Comment: where is the image file? is it in Assests or drawablle or file system??

Comment: I try to use an image that is in an image view. I upload the image to the imageView from the image gallery and then convert the image in the imageview to bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can look Fabric library. For twitter process usually using Fabric library.

You can look Fabric document: 
https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html

Also this is github link: 
https://github.com/fabric/fabric

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Image Description", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Share this via"));
```

Comment: Thank you shridutt, but still getting the error: Failed to insert image java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)